# How to hide Android title bar in dark mode?

Tags: android, material-design, titlebar

I'm using `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` for my activity. My goal is to create an activity with no title bar and make the notification bar background as same as app background colour. Everything works fine under normal condition. But when I enable dark theme from the device settings, the title bar suddenly appears. How can I get rid of title bar for both dark light theme?

Comment: can you please add more details like your style.xml / code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default in the themes folder, there will be a normal one and night version
change the parent theme in both to  `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"` like below
[image]

and the theme in manifest to style name in these two themes(same name) for me here `android:theme="@style/Theme.Advice">` in manifest

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should write those source code in code. Don't share pictures of source code.

Comment: @Istiak there isn't particular code needed here other than what I have already mentioned in text, I put pictures for clarity and context

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why is has not been mentioned yet but `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar` worked way better for me.
Just in case someone is still searching for another solution than the provided ones.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to the Android Manifest file and change NoActionBar to NoTitleBar https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/20749671.html

Answer (score -1):

you can do it programmatically as well :

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
this.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

add this in you oncreate call and before setcontent view.

as :

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        this.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
```